# I want to remember a (NSIndexPath *)indexPath for later deleting, but crashed

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, memory

I define a member like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSIndexPath *deletingIndexPath; //记录当前需要删除的行
```

And assign it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    deletingIndexPath = indexPath;
    ...
}
```

And use it in another CallBack Function

```
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:deletingIndexPath,nil];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

And it crashed...

in simulator it says

```
2012-07-10 16:56:54.887 p[20972:16a03] *** Assertion failure in -[NSIndexPath row], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableViewSupport.m:2606
2012-07-10 16:56:54.898 p[20972:16a03] Uncaught exception: Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.
```

Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in ARC ? If not you must retain your instance. The one you're assigning is autoreleased before you can use it. you could use `self.deletingIndexPath = indexPath;` so the instance would be retained by the property

Comment: deletingIndexPath = indexPath; and self.deletingIndexPath = indexPath; are different? God, I forget it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it's different. when you do deletingIndexPath = indexPath; you just assign the C address of the instance. And it is autoreleased later. But when you do self.deletingIndexPath = indexPath; you use the retain property defined before.

Comment: Thank you again. I remember this time.

Comment: I wonder if I retain the indexPath, will Code writen by apple will change the indexPath and affect my deletingIndexPath?